# Usning Lucene Query to test if a document matches

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene queries for a project like the following:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("message", analyzer);
Query log = parser.parse("something OR name=mustafa");
```

Is there any posiblity to use this `Query` object with some sort of Map or POJO to test if that object matches the query? I know this is not intended usage of Lucene and it works on `IndexSearcher` but it would be useful to me.

Example what I have in mind:

```
Map<String,Object> a = {"message": "xx", "name": "mustafa"}
Map<String,Object> b = {"message": "xx", "name": "osman"}

SomeSearcher.matches(log, a) == true
SomeSearcher.matches(log, b) == false
```

Comment: You want to have an in-memory index from text to Java objects? Or what does your question mean? Can you give an example? If so, how do you create the Lucene index for your POJOs?

Comment: I mean without creating an index, as this query consists of some objects like BooelanQuery, TermQuery etc. can we test them without actually creating an index.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can use `org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory`

This way, your requirement to test out completely from memory is satisfied and also it would require very less changes to move to disk implementation after POC phase.